# Getting strange behaviour on changing image in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimageview

I have 4 image views which I am changing images when user move to next and previos page as below images show. All 4 image view are attached with single `IBOutletCollection` and I differentiate with different tags, but What happend it works fine when I am not changing their image name and it create problem when I move next button and change image name of second Image, I am changing second image name and its y position, but rest of all change their y position, I don't know what happend?
[image: First Image]
[image: Second Image]

You can see on second image 3rd and 4th dot move up but I didn't change their position.

```
           UIImageView * imageView = [_currentlySelectedImage objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blueDot_btn.png"];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x, 232, 17, 18);
```

The `_currentlySelectedImage` is my `IBOutletCollection` of Images and `currentIndex` is the current index.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It keeps the image for your previous imageViews when you move to next page.. What you need to do is change the image of previous ImageViews to those circle images with no color.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get you, I don't need to change image of previous.

Comment: yes u need to change the previous images back to the plain white images.

Answer (score 0):

in your screenshot look like the origin of the dots is the same, try setting to the images in your nib file big enough to contain both images and use view mode 'center', when you need to change image just assign a new UIImage to the UIImageView without change the frame

Answer (score 0):

Finally got solution, after deselect option of `user Autolayout` from nib file. Thats strange but it solved.